# How can we shift ob_item pointer in Python tuple if it is static array?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, python-internals

I am currently reading the Python 2.7 source code and got stuck with the following piece of code, in [`tupleobject.h`](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Include/tupleobject.h#l26):

```
PyObject *ob_item[1];
```

and in [`tupleobject.c` (`PyTuple_SetItem`)](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Objects/tupleobject.c#l151):

```
p = ((PyTupleObject *)op)->ob_item + i;
```

How can we shift pointer by `i` if `ob_item` is an array of one `PyObject`?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390331/why-use-array-size-1-instead-of-pointer

Answer (score 1):

It's how arrays and pointers can be used interchangeable. So it's equivalent to

```
p = &((PyTupleObject *)op)->ob_item[i];
```

[Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c/1641963#1641963) goes a little more into detail.